# java инициализация переменных в класса

Tags: java, классы, наследование, инициализация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом возможно инициализировать матрицу в методе `init()` класса `Matrix`, чтобы строки и столбцы имели значения из метода `main`? Получается, что сразу вызывается конструктор родительского класса `RunnableTask`, потом идет переход в метод `init()` класса `Matrix` и матрица имеет нулевой размер. А нужно чтобы в методе `init()` класса `Matrix`, матрица имела размер `5*5`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RunnableTask matrix = new Matrix(5, 5);
}

public abstract class RunnableTask {
    public abstract void runTask();
    public abstract void init();

    public void run() {
        runTask();
    }

    public RunnableTask() {
        init();
    }
}

public class Matrix extends RunnableTask {
    int rows;
    int cols;

    int matrix[][];

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        matrix = new int[rows][cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = i * j;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void runTask() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.out.println();

            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может убрать метод `init` из `RunnableTask`? По сути он дублирует функционал конструктора.

Comment: Нельзя к сожалению убирать метод init(). Вот пытаюсь понять, возможно ли это ? Или просто пошутили, дав такое тестовое.

Comment: инициализация в runTask() также не допустима

Comment: Вообще это очень плохая практика - вызывать из конструктора родителя переопределяемые методы т.к. сначала будет вызван конструктор родительского класса, а потом только конструктор наследника и может быть непредсказуемое поведение (как в данном примере).

Не знаю насколько сильно можно менять код в Вашем задании, но я бы предложил  через конструкторы передавать rows, cols

Comment: Инициализация матрицы и заполнение должны происходить в методе init() класса Matrix. Менять к сожалению нельзя. Было бы можно, уже бы решил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструктор родительского класса вызывается перед выполнением операторов зависимого класса. В данном случае, конструктор класса RunnableTask вызовется перед тем, как будут заданы размеры матрицы. Поэтому возможно только 3 варианта решения:

1 Вызывать init() в конструкторе Matrix:

```
public Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    init();
}
```

2 Поскольку init объявлен public, то можно производить инициализацию RunnableTask после создания объекта

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableTask matrix = new Matrix(5, 5);
        matrix.init();
        matrix.run();
    }
```

3 Заточить класс RunnableTask под матрицу, например с помощью наследования RunnableMatrixTask

Comment: DaysLikeThis большое спасибо. Подходит по условию задачи и работает так как нужно именно первый вариант. Спасибо.

Comment: хотел проголосовать, но пока не могу, рейтинга(репутации) не хватает

Comment: @java_jun Вы можете отметить ответ как решение